# Non-blocking ACE_SOCK_Stream and client disconnect

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, ace

So I am trying to setup a multithreaded server with ACE. I am using non-blocking client sockets to prevent recv()/send() from blocking. The problem is when I use recv() and the client disconnects ungraceful, the result of recv() does not give me a hind that the client disconnected. Is there any other methode to check the connectivity.

Here is a short snippet

```
            char buffer[4096];
            ssize_t bytesReceived = peer.recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            if (bytesReceived < 1 && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                printf("Disconnected:\n");

            }
            else if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                buffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';
                printf(buffer);
            }
```

So if the client disconnects, recv returns -1 but errno is still EWOULDBLOCK.

I also tried to use a short timeout in recv, but it leads to the same result as without just with errno = ETIME(TIME-Out).

Comment: Have you tried some connection timeouts? Mayne some ping sequences?

Comment: Yes but on disconnect recv() waits until the timeout is reached and then returns -1 with errno ETIME. So I am still not able to detect a disconnect. I am not allowed to send "unnecessary" pakets to the client.

Comment: Not recv timeout, but timeout between two data transfers. If you don't receive any data during specified time, you suggest that socket is disconnected.

Comment: This is also not possible because its like a video-server and it could happen that no data is transfered for hours.

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

Comment: Thank you thats a very interessting blog. But the offered sulutions 1,2 are not possible because I cant change the client. 3 is not possible because I am not aware how long the next respond can take. And 4 seems to be not really portable. I dont get why they not use recv() results like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40320/discussion-between-oleg-olivson-and-mathias-holzl)